# Struts 2 File Upload is not working with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, file-upload

Our Application is based on Struts 2 with Spring. Now we are migrating our application to Spring Boot and after migration file upload has stopped working. Any pointers in this regard will be really helpful. Also, there is hardly any help available online for Struts 2 with Spring Boot.
Can't paste the code online :(

Answer (score 4):

Spring Interceptor might be consuming your request, try setting variable **spring.http.multipart.enabled=false** in your application.properties, this worked for me.

Comment: It worked for me. I'm using struts 2 and spring boot 1.5.3. If I could I'd give you more than 1 upvote!

Answer (score 0):

For SpringBoot 2.x set `spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=false`.